# How does the MANIFEST.MF look like in JSF-based project?

Tags: java, jsf, ant

The conditions of the question are slightly artificial, but that's the task. The project has to be built in Apache Ant. The project itself is mainly based on JSF. The task is to write MANIFEST.MF for building the project with an *executed* class mentioned inside. The problem is that there is no entry point like `psvm` in JSF and other similar frameworks. What I found is official documentation for writing MANIFEST.MF files in [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html). Here is the extract from build.xml file that I got for now with the target of building:

```
<target name="build" depends="compile">
    <echo>Building...</echo>
    <buildnumber/>
    <jar destfile="${jarfile}">
        <fileset dir="${classes}" excludes="Test*.class"/>
    </jar>
    <echo>Building DONE!</echo>
</target>
```

I also saw `<manifest>` tags integrated into `<target>`, but that does not match the current task.
So, what do I write in MANIFEST.MF instead of this executable class, or how can I solve it another way?

Comment: JSF does not pose any requirements on a `MANIFEST.MF` file (why do you think there is?). And if you you need a class to be executed when using java -jar ... then you most likely use something like joinfaces or plain springboot, but still nothing JSF related.

Comment: Yes, in my question there is -jar that is mentioned. But can it be solved in another archive extension, i.e. -war?

Comment: Like mentioned before... JSF does not post any requirements on this, so since it is totally unclear what you really want,  this question is not JSF related. And even if it becomes clear, it still is not JSF related since you never start JSF, you start a servlet container or the likes in which JSF runs...

Comment: In my question I already mentioned the mismatch you've described. That's the reason I wrote "how can I solve it another way?". Once again, the conditions of this don't depend on me anyhow.

Comment: Then I have no idea what your question is... In relation to JSF at least. And "JSF based project" is a plain web project, so maybe generalize your question and get help from others that might be put-off by the (wrongfully added) JSF tag and title part...

Comment: @Kukeltje Edit reverted. Whether it is a web app is the point at issue. Not a word about it in the question until your edit.

Comment: There is nothing JSF related in the question besides the usage of the word JSF.  So I voted to close then for it being unclear (thought I already did that years ago, but either no one agrees  or all the others just skip the question.

Comment: sorry forgot to add @user207421 in the previous comment